# Scooter's stop lights not working

Tags: honda, scooter, brake-light, activa

My scooter's stop lights have stopped working when I apply brakes, however tail light still works. I checked for a loose connection but all seems ok. It's a Honda activa

Answer (score 3):

Check the following:

1. the bulb: it has two filaments one can work while the other has failed
2. supply to the switch: if no supply check the fuse.
3. check the switch goes live on the output when the brake is operated.
4. does the socket get a supply when the brake is operated - if no and you have checked the switch then there is a break in the wire to be found.

Comment: Agreed- My first suspect would always be the bulb!

Comment: As an electrician I started to notice the fault was often the other end from where you started... but the bulb is normally the easiest to get to and check.

Comment: @Solar Mike I shall check and update you

Comment: As a #5 I'd check for corrosion in the socket which could be blocking contact to the brake light pin on the bulb.

Comment: Bulb is all ok.checked for fuse and supply also only thing remaining is the faulty switch but I am not able to locate that.Any idea where it could be located and how it looks?

Comment: One switch on front brake handle, one on foot brake pedal or both could be at the brake end itself. You should be capable of recognising them - will normally have two wires going to the switch...

Answer (score 0):

Check the combi break, may be the cables are wrong fixed, check the combi break unit. Same issues happed to me.